# Question about proof of stake

Tags: proof-of-stake

Can someone explain to me how proof of stake works in detail? And in particular, which is the difference (if it exists) between proof of stake in general and Casper protocol of Ethereum? 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of stake (PoS) is a class of consensus algorithms that utilize digital assets to secure a blockchain. There are many different PoS implementations. Differences include what is staked -- in some cryptocurrencies (e.g., PeerCoin), all coins in a wallet are staked like interest in a bank; in others (e.g., the proposed Casper protocol for Ethereum), stakers are bonded and can lose the amount being staked.

Casper is a subset of PoS algorithms. And it doesn't really make sense (at least to me) to ask how an element of a set differs from the set.

Comment: Just one doubt: in pow the first who finds the nonce broadcast the block into the network and then the nodes control its correctness and then the block is add to the blockchain. In case of pos, how to decide who “mines” (or validates)  a particular block? The one in the validator’s pool who have much money, decide and in case he does some malicious moves, he loses the money? Or anyone can stake money and “vote” for a block and then the block with the higher number of votes is the one that will be added at the blockchain? Sorry, i’m a little bit confuse...

Comment: There are different approaches for different PoS schemes. There is no "one way" for PoS validator selection or other aspects of the staking process. Of course, any specific PoS scheme (e.g. Casper) must make a choice about all these things.

Comment: Oh, perfect! Now it's all clear! I believed that there was a common way to use pos! The only "common" factor is that there are no more hash computations but there is the concept of stake that one can use. The way to use this concept is different depending on who implements it. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Exactly, The stake can be obtained by different ways right from deposit onto the cryptocurrency blockchain to other mechanisms depending on who deploys it. Thanks!!!